# suggest a textbook on calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the recommended textbooks for introductory calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/what-are-the-recommended-textbooks-for-introductory-calculus)

Hi, i am a software engg. and math was never my favourite. I somehow dragged thru the math i had to do in college to earn my degree. But my brother (7 years younger aged 15) *does* have an aptitude for math. i have seen him cruise thru his high school texts with little or no difficulty. He also says he wants to be a mechanical engineer (and backs up his claim by cleaning up and servicing my [motorcycle](http://www.royalenfield.com/Motorcycles/classic-500.aspx) incessantly) anyways he is 15 now and sadly his syllabus hasnt introduced to almost *any* calculus. I know he has to learn a lot of calculus if he is to excel in the Entrance exams for engg colleges in India.So what would you suggest is a good text to start with (in calculus) ? something that shall explain the basics but shall also take the reader to the more advanced and challenging places in calculus ?

TL; DR :

So what would you suggest is a good text to start with (in calculus) ? something that shall explain the basics but shall also take the reader to the more advanced and challenging places in calculus ?

Answer (score 2):

Good books on Calculus :

- Calculus by Thomas Finney
- Elementary Analysis: The theory of Calculus by Kenneth Ross.
- Differential and Integral Calculus : Richard Courant.
- You can see [this link](http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/#Calculus) as well.