# Calculus book with interesting examples

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I need to prepare presentation about calculus, paying special attention for examination of function of one variable. I am not very advances in the topic, but I'm looking for book which contains interesting, not fundamental, examples from fields like continuity of functions, limits, differentiability.

Unfortunately, I didn't learn from english book (english isn't my national language), so books, from which I learned, contained examples for beginners, which could show just problem. According to differentiability there was just mention that, for example, function y=|x| is not differentiable in x=0, and I'm looking for examples not so obvious. For example Weierstrass function is interesting example in that field.

I didn't find book more complicated, different than basics for students. 
This could be student's book or notebook.
I ask for help because I have no experience with foreign books for analysis, calcus.

I will be grateful, if someone decides to help me and to recommend a book

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63504/suggest-textbook-on-calculus?lq=1