# What textbook should I get to self-learn Calculus?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, education, self-learning

I did not have the option to take calculus during high school. I would like to pick up this subject during my free time.

I am a software engineer. I would like to improve my understanding of maths.

What textbook should I buy to understand Calculus.

I found "Calculus made easy" been quoted many times as a simple and effective textbook. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_Made_Easy

I am not sure if it covers similar topics in high school calculus.

I seek your advice.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/what-are-the-recommended-textbooks-for-introductory-calculus?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/which-calculus-text-should-i-use-for-self-study?rq=1

Comment: I haven't read "Calculus made easy", so it would be hasty to judge. But from the wikipedia link, it seems to be a bit outdated. Published in 1910, it doesn't seem to appeal to modern definitions used in calculus (for example, epsilon-delta definition of continuity), but rather infinitesimals. This is only my inference from the wiki article.

Comment: That said, I am sure it is great textbook. I just think that, as a start you might want to expose yourself first to the modern treatment of calculus. Perhaps after, you could learn about infinitesimals.

Comment: @Prism: I read the original once, also Martin Gardner's edition. While Gardner has done a very nice job, the book is mainly of historical interest.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Dear André, thanks for sharing your view on the book!

Comment: You might try the Khan Academy videos. I prefer books myself (I'm old fashioned) so I've never looked at these videos, but I often see people recommending them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently studying a double degree in Mathematics and Information Technology at the Queensland University of Technology in Australia. The prescribed textbook for the calculus unit is Basic Technical Mathematics with Calculus, SI Version, Ninth Edition (9th Edition), which can be found:

[http://www.amazon.com/Technical-Mathematics-Calculus-Version-Edition/dp/013506712X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013506712X)

Not only does the textbook cover calculus, but other preparatory concepts that may help you with your learning.