# How to learn calculus for beginners?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, self-learning, education

As a precalculus student interested in teaching myself calculus, where should I start and how should I go about learning?

This question is different than past questions as I am not solely interested in finding a book.

Comment: Start with derivatives and the motivation for them.

Comment: You might want to get a textbook first.

Comment: Book recommendations would be helpful

Comment: Book recommendations: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322892/calculus-book-recommendations-for-complete-beginner?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/which-calculus-text-should-i-use-for-self-study?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449205/what-textbook-should-i-get-to-self-learn-calculus?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614376/calculus-self-taught-books

Comment: @Amzoti This question is different than past questions as I am not solely interested in finding a book.

Comment: You ask a question with two halves: First, where should you start: the answer is to get a community (which you've done) and to get a textbook. The second half is how you should go about learning. This has also already been answered at length (e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-do-you-go-about-learning-mathematics )

Comment: @okarin Your question is probably appropriate for the nearly-in-beta-SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education. 

Check out the proposal and commit to it if you're interested. Then we can get it off the ground and get the site in beta!

Comment: @Xoque55 That nearly-in-beta-SE seems more focused on teaching of math, rather than teaching of math to oneself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \newcommand{\dd}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}
\newcommand{\limh}{\lim_{h \to 0}} $ 
**Disclaimer**: This is kind of long because I copied a lot (not all) of it from an old TeX file I wrote.  This will be a lot to take in for a beginner, but it provides a much more rigorous foundation in calculus than most textbooks offer.  It's best that this be read in supplement to a work explicitly intended for the instruction of basic calculus.  Enjoy, OP.

Okay, so the first thing anyone learns about calculus is derivatives.  You should, by now, be familiar with the equation $$ m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} $$
Where $m$ is the slope of a line.  We can rewrite this: $$ m=\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0} $$
In calculus, we want to generalize the slope.  We don't just want to have the slope of a straight line, because that is very limited.  So what about the "slope" of a curve?  Surely 
we can approximate it at least.  What is the slope of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=1$?  well, we could try $$ m=\frac{f(1+1)-f(1)}{1}=3 $$
and that would get us an approximation, but that's kind of weak.  Let's make the difference smaller!
$$ m=\frac{f(1+.1)-f(1)}{.1}=2.1 $$
Hmm.  That should be closer.  Can we make the difference arbitrarily small?  Since you've done precalc, you should be familiar with limits.  So let's say $$\begin{align} m&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^2-1^2}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2h+h^2}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}2+h=2 \end{align}$$

So we would say the "slope" at $x=1$ of $f(x)=x^2$ is $2$.  In general, we say $$ \dd{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$
Where $\dd{f(x)}{x}$ is our "slope," known as a *derivative* (the shorthand for the derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x)$).  The next section will prove important properties of derivatives, such as the *chain rule* and *product rule*, and generally proves the derivative of $x^n$ with respect to $x$.

Note:  When we have $\dd yx$, the d's serve much the same purpose as the $\Delta$ signs do in $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.  $\text dy$ is actually an infinitesimal number denoting the change in $y$, and $\dd yx$ notes that change in proportion to the change in $x$ over an infinitely small interval.

---

First we will prove the chain rule, which states $$\dd{f(g(x))}{x}=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$
Consider functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
$$f'(x)=\limh \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
$$g'(x)=\limh \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
Let us define *u* and *v* as follows:
$$u=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)$$
$$v=\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}-g'(x)$$
Note that as $h \to 0$, $u,v \to 0$.

Now, we rearrange the equations:
\begin{align*}
u&=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x) \\
u+f'(x)&=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
h(u+f'(x))&=f(x+h)-f(x) \\
h(u+f'(x))+f(x)&=f(x+h)
\end{align*}
Through the same process, we can obtain that $$h(v+g'(x))+g(x)=g(x+h)$$
Now, consider the derivative of $f(g(x))$:
\begin{align*}
\dd{f(g(x))}{x}&=\limh \frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h} \\
&=\limh \frac{f\left(g(x)+h(v+g'(x))\right)-f(g(x))}{h} \\
&=\limh \frac{f(g(x))+(h(v+g'(x)))(u+f'(g(x)))-f(g(x))}{h} \\
&=\limh \frac{h(v+g'(x))(u+f'(g(x)))}{h} \\
&=\limh (v+g'(x))(u+f'(g(x))) \\
&=g'(x)\cdot f'(g(x))
\end{align*}

Now, let $f(x)=e^x$ for some constant $e$, and allow $f(x)=f'(x)$:
\begin{align*}
e^x&=\dd{(e^x)}{x} \\
e^x&=\limh \frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h} \\
e^x&=\limh \frac{e^xe^h-e^x}{h} \\
e^x&=\limh \frac{e^x(e^h-1)}{h} \\
1&=\limh\frac{e^h-1}{h} \\
\limh h&=\limh e^h-1 \\
\limh h+1&=\limh e^h \\
\limh (h+1)^{\frac{1}{h}}&=e
\end{align*}
Substituting $x=\frac{1}{h}$, we obtain:
$$e=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$
We define $f^{-1}(x):=\log{x}$ such that $\log{e^x}=e^{\log{x}}=x$.

We will now consider the derivative of $\log{x}$:
$$ \dd{(e^x)}{x}=e^x $$
Substituting $u=e^x$, we get the following:
\begin{align*}
\dd{u}{(\log{u})}&=u \\
\dd{(\log{u})}{u}&=\frac{1}{u}
\end{align*}

Now, we consider the function $x^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{C}$. We know that $x^n=e^{n \log{x}}$. Consider the derivative of $x^n$ with respect to $x$:
$$\dd{(x^n)}{x}=\dd{(e^{n \log{x}})}{x} $$
Here, we let $u=n \log{x}$:
\begin{align*}
\dd{(x^n)}{x}&=\dd{(e^u)}{u}\cdot \dd{(n \log{x})}{x} \\
&=e^u\cdot n\cdot \frac{1}{x} \\
&=e^{n \log{x}}\cdot \frac{n}{x} \\
&=x^n\cdot \frac{n}{x} \\
&=n x^{n-1}
\end{align*}

It's also worth noting that $\dd{f(x)g(x)}x=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$, which is called the product rule.  The proof is as follows:
$$\begin{align} \dd {f(x)g(x)}x&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x+h)g(x)+f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)(g(x+h)-g(x))+g(x)(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}+g(x)\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x) \end{align}$$

Comment: FYI, limits are not standard material for precalc. They are often mentioned (more often outside the US, I believe), but just as often they are not.

Comment: Really? I was always under the impression that that was part of the point of precalc.  I have a weird history of schooling which ended up (luckily) skipping any equivalent of precalc.

Comment: I agree with the "(luckily)" qualifier: my memory of precalc is a random collection of jumbled topics that seemed to lead nowhere interesting. Of course, they were the beginnings of many interesting topics, which I know now! But I was given neither unity nor motivation for most of them, and I saw no structure at all. Even if I had learned limits in precalc I probably would have forgotten them had I not taken calculus immediately afterwards…

Comment: I have done limits in precalc.

Answer (score 3):

Look at KhanAcademy, they have great explanation for calculus (start by order). https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus

Also see MIT | Big Picture courses on calculus. http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA61F034AC6BB546D

For textbook I recommend this one:  Calculus Made Easy - Silvanus P. Thompson

[http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Made-Easy-Silvanus-Thompson/dp/0312185480](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312185480)

It costs only 17 box and has great reviews for example: 
This book is fantastic! If only I had it in college. I happened across Calc Made Easy in a bookstore on a business trip. In college, I was a math major and, at first, struggled through the concept of calculus and was intimidated by the terminology. I haven't done calculus in 25 years, but I read this whole book in one afternoon covering both limits, as well as differential and integral calculus. I cannot believe how easy this author makes these concepts.

Every 1st year calculus student should read this book. After grasping the concepts in Calc Made Easy, then you can concentrate on the algebraic manipulations you need to practice in order to solve the integrals and differencials in you're classroom textbooks. Reading this book you will look like a genius. But, more importantly you'll really appreciate the beauty of calculus and probably be motivated to do well in this class. Good luck and enjoy it.

Also you must buy the paper edition and not the kindle edition since this last one doesn't show off the symbols and graphs...