# Soft question: What are some good calculus resources

Tags: calculus, self-learning, learning

I am a high school junior searching for decent calculus texts to strengthen my grasp on the subject. I am going advanced than my school course and am currently learning multi-variable calculus from MIT OCW but I decided to go through everything once again to better understand the subject. I do practice problems a lot but sometimes I cannot evaluate seemingly complicated integrals. I am currently going through 'Inside Interesting Integrals'. I find it very good, but I was wondering whether there are any more decent texts. I did my basics of Calculus 1 and 2 from Khan Academy and MIT OCW.

Please suggest some good resources, I'm willing to do all the hardwork to be a better mathematician :)

Comment: Have a look at the preface and the table of contents of the book _Understanding Analysis_ by Stephen Abbott, and see if it satisfies what you are looking for.

Comment: "I cannot evaluate seemingly complicated integrals" There is nothing wrong with that. Many mathematicians and computer algebra systems have the same problem. What is wrong with the standard calculus texts? Have you looked in them?

Comment: @Somos What do you consider 'standard calculus texts'?

Comment: Anton, Apostal, Stewert, Spivak, Strang,Thomas. See [MSE question 128220](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128220) "Which calculus text should ... use for self study" for more examples. Also [Wikipedia article Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As for the standard texts, I have a hard copy of N. Piskunov and PDFs of some of the other books. I want a lot of problems to practice but the books I have contain mostly theory.