# Is Introduction to Calculus and Analysis by Courant a good book for a first Calculus course for a beginner?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, self-learning, book-recommendation

I have Courant's Introduction to Calculus and Analysis and also have Spivak's Calculu's and Thommas-Finney Calculus with analytic Geometry, I'm finishing my precalculus studies, and I don't have much experience with calculus.

I want to become really good at math, and I want to know (Real) calculus, so I'd like to know if Courant is good for a first approach or should I start with Spivak?

Comment: I just checked your profile and note that you have asked essentially the same question four times. That is bad manners on this site. Please delete the others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What book is better for learning calculus Courant, Apostol or Spivak?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993616/what-book-is-better-for-learning-calculus-courant-apostol-or-spivak)

Answer (score 1):

Courant and Spivak are classic excellent texts, from different eras. I suggest you use both, in parallel. You will learn a lot comparing the two approaches.

A word of warning: both these books work at a level of rigor that you may not be familiar with from your precalculus studies. Thomas will have a larger collection of relatively routine exercises.

Whatever route you choose, be sure to work lots of exercises.

Comment: What books could be useful before start with Courant and Spivak, in order of understand clearly what they explain?