# about calculus books.

Tags: calculus

I need a calculus book that has all the details or is closest to it. If one book for calculus would not be enough to understand concepts, kindly recommend books that don't have overlapping concepts.
    It might also be fine if the divisions are Integral Calculus, Differential Calculus, but please recommend a book which contains everything in it in details.

Comment: "All details" of calculus would fill a library (Euler did, and calculus was barely starting)... please narrow it down: what do you know already, what do you need (and what do you need it for)? In any case, the tags are completely off-base.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the recommended textbooks for introductory calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/what-are-the-recommended-textbooks-for-introductory-calculus)

Answer (score 2):

> I need a calculus book that has all the details or is closest to it.

[Spivak](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098918).

Comment: Remark: Spivak's book does not cover all of calculus (not by far); however, it has all the details regarding those portions that it *does* cover.

Answer (score 1):

If you want in depth knowledge of Calculus then I would recommend Thomas's Calculus. It covers all the Calculus you need upto second order differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

To arouse interest in Calculus- the calculus story : a mathematical adventure

To easily pass AP calculus BC and Further maths paper- the Calculus Lifesaver

To get full mastery on Calculus - Thomas' calculus, Early transcendentals