# Brushing up on Calc

Tags: calculus, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am an engineering major. I have taken calc 1-3 and did very well in each course. However, I feel that I did well mostly by learning the tricks and feel that I need a better intuitive understanding of the fundamentals of calculus. I am looking for a book to help me (preferably a cheaper one, not a $100 textbook). I would appreciate some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: See this link for single-variable calculus: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901622/single-variable-calculus-reference-recommendations

Comment: See if *A First Course in Calculus* by Lang suits your needs. Used copies aren't too expensive on Amazon. It's more concise than most comparable textbooks. The theory is at a sufficient level of rigour for most of those who want a more in-depth view of calculus, but without using the formal definition of a limit and without proving the more difficult theorems.

Comment: If you are looking for a Calculus textbook, then Stewart is a pretty good one. You can pick up a used hardcover 5th edition for $6 on amazon. If you aren't taking a class, then there is no need to purchase new textbooks.

http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Early-Transcendentals-5th-Edition/dp/B000VTJ2QS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the recommended textbooks for introductory calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/what-are-the-recommended-textbooks-for-introductory-calculus)

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to Prof. Strang's [textbook](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/textbook/) on Calculus regularly whenever I need a quick refresher. It is heavy on intuition. While there are many books out there on Calculus, the following free ebooks that I stumbled upon recently maintain the right balance between intuition and rigor, in my opinion.

[Calculus and Linear Algebra. Vol. 1: Vectors in the Plane and One-Variable Calculus - Wilfred Kaplan and Donald J. Lewis](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/s/spobooks/5597602.0001.001/--calculus-and-linear-algebra-vol-1-vectors-in-the-plane)

[Calculus and Linear Algebra. Vol. 2: Vector Spaces, Many-Variable Calculus, and Differential Equations - Wilfred Kaplan and Donald J. Lewis](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/s/spobooks/5597602.0002.001/--calculus-and-linear-algebra-vol-2-vector-spaces-many)