# Theory book on limits and integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am a high schooler and my school curriculum is pre bad, I know how to solve integrals and find limits but I was looking for a base book to how we arrived at these complex methods or why do we need them , what do they signify, is there any good book or thesis I can read that would help me learn from absolute 0 instead of making me solve questions without any sense of why I would appreciate it

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but while I'm searching, I'll say: Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: Is your "why" question regarding the *mathematical* motivation for the steps (i.e., why are they allowed in mathematics) or the *practical* motivation for them (i.e., why does anyone care about computing integrals)?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901622/single-variable-calculus-reference-recommendations