# What are some good Calculus Textbooks?

Tags: calculus

I am a first year undergraduate student pursuing a BS in Mathematical Sciences with a Concentration in Applied Mathematics, and I am currently taking a Calculus II course. I am using the book $\textit{Thomas' Calculus Early Transcendentals} $ $13^{th}Edition$. I have been using this book for $2$ semesters now, but I have noticed that it  does not go into detail in certain important topics, and lacks of proofs (when they give a proof it is too discursive without much "traditional" proving behind it). Also, the examples and the exercises at the end of each chapter are really basic and do not challenge me at all. Therefore, my question is: What books should I look into, as a supplement of this one?

Comment: I don't know if Calculus II for you means integral calculus or calculus of several variables.  If it's the former, then Michael Spivak's *Calculus* is the standard "rigorous" single-variable calculus textbook.

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/self-study-calculus/ Try this blog kind of post on self learning calculus.

Comment: **This duplicates a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395) earlier than the precedent.**

Answer (score 1):

The Calculus book I used was Stewart's Calculus as there were challenge problems at the end of each section. These problems required basic proof and their solutions were often two liners.

If you have not taken a course on proof writing, Spivak's Calculus may be out of reach since it is a very elementary book in Real Analysis (The theory behind Calculus). If you can solve the problems in Spivak easily, you may want to look at Abott's book or Baby Rudin.